# Open and read txt file in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to open a txt file and read from it here's the code:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("TrackData/vehicle_points.txt");
```

`TrckData` is a folder in my web application.
but i get this error :

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\TrackData\vehicle_points.txt'.

My project is not even in C Driver, I don't know where it gets that url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASP.Net applications are stored in a different folder, and here you have given a relative which may vary according to asp.net executable path.

Please use

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("TrackData/vehicle_points.txt");
 StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path);
```

this will surely work..

Answer (score 5):

`File.OpenText` will start with the path being the current directory - this is the directory the executable is in.

You need to give it the correct *full* path to the file.

Comment: What if i wanted to run my project on another computer?

Comment: @rNuǝɹɐ - You still need to provide the full path. How you do that is up to you (pick up the root path from configuration, database, anything else).

Answer (score 3):

Can use

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "TrackData/" +fileName);
```

Comment: This works great from a generic class file.

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/TrackData/") + Textbox.Text);

string read = sr.ReadLine();

if(read != null)
{
    Response.Write(read);
}
else
{
    Response.Write("nothing to display");
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!! I think your answer could be much more useful if you give an explanation of what was the error instead of dropping some code without any context. Please refer to [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is the one:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("filename.txt");
StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(path);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some text explaining why this answer is better than the one that 's already been accepted. using `File` or `StreamReader` are different things, so they can't really be compared.